# Fi Binary Number

Tags: number-theory

A Fi-binary number is a number that contains only 0 and 1. It does not contain any leading 0. And also it does not contain 2 consecutive 1. The first few such number are 1, 10, 100, 101, 1000, 1001, 1010, 10000, 10001, 10010, 10100, 10101 and so on. I have n. How to calculate the nth Fi-binary number ?

Comment: Actually, I *don't* have to calculate the $n$th FiBinary number, *you* do. So, what steps have you taken to do so?

Comment: My question is , How to calculate nth Fi-binary number ? n can be 10^9, so what sill be the 10^9th  Fi-binary number ?

Comment: I know what your question is. My question remains: what steps have you taken toward answering your question?

Comment: I attempt a naive step , check the number one by one, it is Fi-binary or not? if it is , take the number in the queue of Fi-binary number. if queue size is n then the last value of queue is answer. but it should be optimized . It has a pattern to calculate , I think . I am asking for this pattern.

Comment: The question is interesting. Describe your efforts **within the question**, and show your attempts towards reaching a solution on your own. Thus, you will increase your chances of being taken more seriously, and perhaps even getting some proper answers to your question.

Comment: I already described my attempt . My attempt was so naive. but it has a pattern. The pattern is related to fibonacci number, I thik  . but how ? I can't figure out. please help.@ barak manos

Comment: @MSHossain Again: describe your efforts **within the question**.

Comment: attempt a naive step , check the number one by one, it is Fi-binary or not? if it is , take the number in the queue of Fi-binary number. if queue size is n then the last value of queue is answer. but it should be optimized . It has a pattern to calculate , I think . I am asking for this pattern

Comment: So, which part of "within the question" is it that you don't understand? "Within the question" means **not** here in the comments, but in the actual question itself.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson, I understood the question but I ask for a optimized way to calculate .

Comment: I got the solution by  Batominovski... no need to explain anything now.

Comment: Yes, there is still a need to edit your question in accordance with the suggestions in the comment, for the benefit of others coming to this question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  Let $F_k$ denote the $k$-th Fibonacci number; i.e., $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, and $F_k=F_{k-1}+F_{k-2}$ for all integers $k\geq 2$.  Every positive integer $n$ can uniquely be written as a sum of nonconsecutive pairwise distinct Fibonacci numbers $F_k$'s with $k\geq 2$.    If $n=\sum_{j=1}^m\,F_{k_j}$ is such a representation, then the $n$-th Fi-binary number is $\sum_{j=1}^m\,10^{k_j-2}$.  If you are talking about the base-$2$ representation, then replace $10$ by $2$.

Comment: but how the idea about the final result come ? explain please @Batominovski